# Про слайд шоу на PHP

Tags: php

Это код который позволяет показать слайд с 4 комментами, прошу подсказать как написать код для стрелок, которые позволят двигать комменты по-одному. На PHP, а не на JS [image: вот картинка]

```
<div class="comment-pages">
       <a href="#" class="link"><i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i></a>

       <?php
          for ($j = 0; $j < $count / 4; $j++) {
       ?>
          <a href="?page=<?= $j ?>" class="link link-circle"> <i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a>
       <?php
          };
       ?>
       <a href="#" class="link"><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: На пыхе только `GET, POST, ...` запросами, либо сокетом (что будет полнейшим извратом).

Comment: да, круглые работают именно с GET, но для стрелок как это организовать, ведь число кругов соответсвует числу страниц, а стрелка должна бежать наверно по массиву...

Comment: Писать фронт на пыхе - это довольно креативная затея. Возьми из $_GET текущее значение и на стрелки повесь +1 и -1 от него - соответственно

Comment: Знаю на JS умею, просто это домашнее задание, я еще учусь пхп

Comment: Ну так сделайте ajax запрос со следующим id и доставайте его

Comment: С помощью $_GET я получаю четверку комментов(то есть page- это лимит для круглых), а как получить один коммент? При этом не ограничивая лимит 4 на одном page...?

Comment: Обновлять содержимое страницы всё-равно придётся с помощью JS. AJAX тоже использует JS. Нажатия генерируют события JS. Так что без JS не обойтись.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то у вас идет `page=1` - страница, `limit=4`, лимит на страницу. Если вы хотите, чтобы стрелка сдвигала не все 4, а по одному, то вам просто нужно убирать 1 элемент и добавлять следующий в конец.

Comment: Да, да, да... именно это. Круги сдвигают все 4, а стрелки должны  по одному, круги работают... Но не знаю как это организовать со стрелками

Comment: Потребуется просто завести еще одно значение которое будет увеличиваться автоматом при нажатии на стрелку `++GET['next']` и уменьшаться на другую стрелку `--GET['next']`. а это число у вас будет говорить с какого начинаем выводить. вот собственно и все. Добавить еще пару проверок если `0 >= next` и `next <= count` - если условие не совпадает просто говорим что `next = 0` или `next = count`, чтобы это считалось началом и концом.